# Travel from Belgium to Romania with French "Récépissé de renouvellement de Titre de Séjour"

Tags: visas, schengen, indian-citizens, france, romania

I am non-EU citizen and residing in France. My visa is expired but I have the "Récépissé de renouvellement de Titre de Séjour" (i.e. a visa renewal receipt). My visa is a student type D visa with multiple entries.

**Question:**
Will I be able to travel from Brussels to Bucharest and back again?

Comment: Is your visa expired? Have you already got a residence permit or will this be your initial residence permit?

Comment: Yes, my Visa is currently expired.
This is my 2nd year in France, so am not particularly sure if it would count as having had a Residence Permit (sorry, but the French system is still a bit confusing for me).
All I was told was that since I have the Récépissé de renouvellement de Titre de Séjour, it should be as good as a normal Visa, entitling free movement in Schengen area.

Comment: The residence permit is the Titre de Séjour. You should have obtained your first one as soon as you arrived in France, as I understand it.

Comment: I was under the impression a Type D French Visa is equivalent to a residence permit (with allowance of stay of upto 90 days in other Schengen states on 1 visit). Please correct me if am wrong.
Also, since am on a student visa, we were never supposed to get any additional permits except for an OFII stamp.

Comment: What is your citizenship? Are you concerned about entering Romania or about returning to France?

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding for readers. The question is basically, is a "visa renewal receipt" valid for travel to Romania? The OP had a valid student permit and applied for a renewal. He is waiting for his new visa and in the mean time, he only has a receipt proving he should get a new visa.

Comment: @MichaelHampton as I understand it most D visas these days function as a titre de sejour for one year so there's no need to get a residence permit until the visa expires (the second year).

Comment: @JonathanReez, it would be Indian. I am aware that returning to France wouldn't be an issue as the French authorities clearly recognise it, after all it is issued by them.

Comment: @JonathanReez, my main concern is whether I will be able to board a flight from Brussels and secondary concern being whether Bucharest will recognise a French Récépissé.

Comment: @MichaelHampton for students on type D visa the OFII Stamp on it essentially "converts" that visa into a Titre de Séjour (Reisdence permit).

to OP,  Romania allows Schengen visa holders (at least dual entries) to enter the country (http://mae.ro/en/node/2040)  subject to you not exhausting the number of days/right of stay. But since yours is being renewed, perhaps you could ask the romanian consulate?

Comment: @h21 OK, that makes sense.

Comment: @h21, yes you are right, ideally a Schengen visa gives access to associate states + 4 states including Romania, even if it is a Récépissé. But better to be sure than to be sorry! I have already written to MAE at Romania but they seem to be taking time to respond. Will wait and see.

Comment: @K.K all the best ! Do update back so we know what's the consulate's stand. Also, do bring a printout of their reply with you too (if they say you are allowed to travel).

Comment: @MichaelHampton The terminology can be a bit confusing. “Titre de séjour” means any document entitling the holder to reside in France. A “carte de séjour” (residence permit on a plastic card) is a type of “titre de séjour“, as is a long-stay visa (or “VLS–TS” for “visa long séjour valant titre de séjour”) or a “carte de résident” (something akin to a permanent residence card).

Comment: Someone who holds a VLS-TS is not expected to apply for a separate *carte de séjour* before the end of their first year in France, at which point what they are applying for their second *titre de séjour*. That's why the *récépissé* mentions a “renouvellement”.

Comment: Conversely, someone who holds a *carte de séjour* is not expected to apply for visas anymore. The visa sticker in the passport and the plastic card permit fulfil the same role, legally speaking.

Answer (score 1):

According to the Romanian [Ministry of Foreign Affairs](http://evisa.mae.ro/CheckResult?cetatenieId=106&scopVizitaId=7&tipDocumentId=16&isBiometric=2):

> Given the conditions selected previously, you need a visa in order to travel to Romania.
>
> However, should you fit into one of the situations below, you are exempt from the Romanian visa requirement, for stays that of no more than 90 days during any 180-day period:
>
> ...
>
> •   I hold a residence permit issued by a Schengen member state ;
>
> “**An essential precondition for the equivalence of these visas as Romanian national visas is that they be valid**, namely that the right of stay and validity period not have been used up.";

Therefore the answer is **no**, you would not be allowed to enter Romania without a visa.

Answer (score 1):

To clarify your status and answer some of the questions in the comments, the document you hold does entitle you to leave and reenter France. It is a valid residence document and [listed as such in Prado](https://www.consilium.europa.eu/prado/en/FRA-HP-01002/index.html). [Service-public.fr](https://www.service-public.fr/particuliers/vosdroits/F12189) also states that such a document can be used to return to France. Since the right of stay and validity period attached to your *récépissé* have not been used up, you should be covered by the rules allowing Schengen-area residents to enter Romania.

At the same time, because it is a somewhat unusual document, it's difficult to rule out some issues at the airport in Brussels or at the Romanian border. If the travel is not essential, it could therefore make sense to postpone it.